# Where is Instant Run of Android Studio 3.5?

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.5

I cannot find Instant Run in Android Studio 3.5.  The [release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases) only says Apply Changes is better than Instant Run for Android 8.0 or higher, but does **not** mention removal of Instant Run that supports older versions of Android (as low as Android 5).  The t[ool page of Instant Run](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run) redirects to [Build and run your app page.](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run) after showing the following contents briefly:

> N Developer Preview users: Instant Run is currently incompatible with
>   the Jack toolchain. This new toolchain is required to use Java 8
>   language features supported by Android N. To learn more, read about
>   the new Java 8 language features and Jack.
>
> We Want Your Feedback! Instant Run is currently available only in
>   Android Studio 2.0, and higher. We will continue to improve the
>   feature in subsequent releases.
>
> If you run into any additional issues, please help by logging bugs in
>   our public Issues Tracker. You can create an issue via this link or by
>   clicking on Help → Submit Feedback directly in Android Studio.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: See this blog post https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/08/android-studio-35-project-marble-goes.html in particular this part: "we removed Instant Run and re-architectured and implemented from the ground-up a more practical approach in Android Studio 3.5 called Apply Changes. Apply Changes uses platform-specific APIs from Android Oreo and higher to ensure reliable and consistent behavior; unlike Instant Run, Apply Changes does not modify your APK"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In android studio 3.5 instant Run is remove.
If you have a problem in app installation multiple time
**Then go to => run Configuration => Installation Option 
==> Default apk ==> install flag ==> -r -t ==>Apply ==> Run**
Then your problem solve of instant run

Comment: I still can't run my app on an Android 4.4 device. It doesn't even show the icon. Everything works fine on my own device which has 7.0. My Android Studio is 3.5.3 atm.